# SwiftUI - confirmationDialog

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a problem with `confrimationDialog`.

I used `confrimationDialog` on the third depth page.
And there are three choices in that `confrimationDialog`.

```
var moreBtn: some View {
    Button(action: {
        opinionSheet.toggle()
    }) {
        Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 14)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
    }
    .confirmationDialog(Text("Opinion"), isPresented: $opinionSheet, titleVisibility: .hidden) { //actionsheet
         Button("Revise") {
             opinionNavigationLink = true
         }
         Button("Delete", role: .destructive) {
             opinionAlert = true
         }
         Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) {
         }
    }
}
```

And I added the `moreBtn` in `navigationBarItems`.

But no matter I clicked which button, I go back to the previous page.

I also use `moreBtn` in that previous page too, but it works as well as I expect.

This is the code I used in the previous page.

```
var moreBtn: some View {
    Button(action: {
        showingSheet.toggle()
    }) {
        Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 14)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
    }
    .confirmationDialog("TravelOn", isPresented: $showingSheet, titleVisibility: .hidden) { //actionsheet
         Button("Revise") {
             navigationLinkActive = true
         }
         Button("Delete", role: .destructive) {
             showingAlert.toggle()
         }
         Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) {
         }
    }
}
```

Is there anyone who had the same problem like this ?!
Please let me know why `confrimationDialog` makes the page go to the previous page.

Thank you in advance. ..

Comment: Please remove duplicated code snippets and other noise and add code showing how `navigationLinkActive` and `showingAlert` are implemented.

Comment: Instead of duplicating your code , try define your own ButtonWithDialog view with binding to the handled var. BTW, there is a risk in your code the the dismiss of the confirmation dialog may be interpreted by SwiftUI as a dismiss of the view containing the button . Before making it a var, does the code inside body work if you put it in the view ?